# Express.json() Not Working in version 4.17.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, mean-stack

I'm trying to learn the MEAN stack I just want to perform the CURD operation. But when I send data in the request body from angular to server I received an empty request body. I don't have any idea where I'm going wrong.

Here is my code

**Route**

```
router.post('/create-user', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  let { name, email, gender, mobile_no, password } = req.body;

  try {
    if (
      !(name && email && gender && mobile_no && password && password.length > 8)
    ) {
      throw new Error(
        `All fields are required name: ${name} , email: ${email} , gender: ${gender} , MobileNo: ${mobile_no} .Password length must be greater then 8 character`
      );
    }
    password = bcrypt.hashSync(password, parseInt(process.env.BCRYPT_SALT));

    // let response = await USER.create({ name, email, gender, mobile_no });
    const token = await jwt.sign(
      { name, email, mobile_no, user_id: response._id },
      process.env.JWT_KEY
    );

    response = response.toObject();
    response['token'] = token;

    res.status(200).json({ err: 0, message: 'User Created', response });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ err: 1, message: error.message, error });
  }
});
```

**Index.js**

```
const User = require('./Routes/user');

// Using middle ware
app.use(cors());
app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);
app.use(express.json());

app.use('/user', User);

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`App started on http://localhost:${PORT}`));
```

**Package.JSON**

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^9.0.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.9"
  }
}
```

**Angular**

```
 create_user(data) {
    return this.http.post(`${environment.BASE_URL}/user/create-user`, data, {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    });
  }

  register_user() {
    const data = this.register_form.getRawValue();

    let aData = new FormData();
    aData.append('name', data.name);
    aData.append('email', data.email);
    aData.append('password', data.password);
    aData.append('image', this.image);
    aData.append('gender', 'Male');

    // this.store.dispatch(loading({ spinner: true }));
    this.user_service.create_user(aData).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log(res);
        this.store.dispatch(loading({ spinner: false }));
      },
      (error) => console.log(error)
    );
  }
```

If I set content-type in my request I received an error.
is this a correct way to data into formdata?

**Http failure response for http://localhost:4000/user/create-user: 400 Bad Request**

Sorry if I do some silly mistake. I'm just learning

Comment: console your data before sending to the server

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
item = {
     name: '', 
     email: '', 
     gender: '', 
     password: ''
   }
  formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(item));
```

In express access data like this:

```
  let data = JSON.parse(req.body.data);
```

If your data contain file:

In Angular:

```
formData.append('user_pic', uploadedFile, uploadedFile.name);
```

In express:

server.js:

```
const expressFileUpload = require("express-fileupload");
app.use(expressFileUpload());
```

Access file in route.js:

```
req.files.user_pic
```